# getJSON won't load in IE (any version)

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using $.getJSON to load in a video gallery from Vimeo and it works fine in all browsers, except in any version of IE. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is the .js file where the getJSON is running:

```
console.log('file load');

var jsonURL = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/1822727/videos.json';

$.getJSON(jsonURL, function(data){
  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
    var videoID = value.id;
    var videoThm = value.thumbnail_large;
    $('#galThms').prepend('<li id="thm' + videoID + '" style="background-image:url(' + videoThm + ');"><a title="' + videoID + '" href="#playVideo"></a></li>');
    console.log('json success');
    });
    $(function() {
      $('.galleryThms a').click(function() {
        $('#loadVideo').slideDown();
        $('.galleryThms a').html('');
        $(this).html('<div class="currentOverlay"><ul><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul></div>');
        $('<div class="watchedVideo"></div>').appendTo($(this).parent());
        $('.galleryThms a').css('background-image', 'url(/images/gallery-play-button.png)');
        $(this).css('background-image', 'none');

        //Embed Video
        var vimeoEmbedID = $(this).attr( "title" );
        $('#loadVideo').html('<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/' + vimeoEmbedID + '?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=57bec7&amp;autoplay=1" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>');

     });

  });
 });
```

The live example can be found here: http://wavesmediagroup.com/weddings/portfolio/

Comment: Try using `$.ajax` and pass in an error handler so you can know what's happening. That's one of the reasons I don't use `$.getJSON`. Also, try a later version of jQuery 1.1 is really old.

Comment: I had jquery 1.11. Just tried upgrading to v2 though to see if that will help. Don't need IE8 anymore so it is about time anyways. If I use ajax, can I just replace getJSON or does the entire syntax change as well? Sorry for the ignorance, newer to Javascript land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a cross domain issue. This article here, http://e-mats.org/2010/01/jquery-getjson-and-the-same-origin-policy, explains in detail that you simply add:

```
?callback=?
```

…at the end of your cross domain JSON file, and jquery handles the rest. So my URL now looks like:

```
http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/1822727/videos.json?callback=?
```

…and it works perfectly!

Comment: I think if you use a later version of jQuery, it detects cross domains and uses jsonp automatically

Comment: I had been using the latest 2.x version.